# How can I filter Mongodb specific document's subdocument

Tags: c#, mongodb

Consider you have Order and OrderDetails. I'm trying to filter order details for the specific order.
For instance if you have document something like this:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "02.04.2020 ...",
      "user": {
        "name": "xx",
        "surname": "yy"
      },
      "orderDetails": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "productId": 5,
          "quantity": 1,
          "state": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "productId": 3,
          "quantity": 4,
          "state": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "productId": 4,
          "quantity": 12,
          "state": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "productId": 7,
          "quantity": 8,
          "state": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "productId": 12,
          "quantity": 9,
          "state": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "01.04.2020 ...",
      "user": {
        "name": "xx",
        "surname": "yy"
      },
      "orderDetails": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "productId": 5,
          "quantity": 1,
          "state": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "productId": 3,
          "quantity": 4,
          "state": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "productId": 4,
          "quantity": 12,
          "state": 2
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is first filtering by order and then state of an order detail. I have a code like this but it always brings correct order with all orderDetails. Seems like it doesn't care about equal filter for orderDetails.
Actually it's working but not filtering. Because I only have 3 types of state(enum) and int values are 1,2,3. Query brings nothing if I give 4.

```
var builder = Builders<Order>.Filter;
var filter = builderk.And(builder.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(elementid)), builder.Eq("orderDetails.state", 3));
var result = _mongoRepository.FindByFilter(filter).ToList();
```

I also tried AnyEq and something like that filters but didn't work.
I will be very happy if anyone can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: What should be the result? Order and all OrderDetails, Order and OrderDetails with correct State or only OrderDetails with correct State?

Comment: It should bring first order with 3 orderDetails. But it brings first order with all orderDetails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation operation for operations such as filter sorting in detail records.

If we continue through the sample, you must first create a filter for your master data.

```
var builderMaster = Builders<Order>.Filter;
var filterMaster = builderMaster.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(elementid));
```

Then you need to create a different filter for the details.
**Important**: You must use the BsonDocument type when creating detail filters. Because you cannot give a specific type when you filter the details.

```
var builderDetail = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filterDetail = builderDetail.Eq("orderDetails.state", 3);
```

Then you can start typing the query.

```
var list = _mongoRepository.Aggregate()
                            .Match(filterMaster)
                            .Unwind("orderDetails")// Name the details.
                            .Match(filterDetail)
                            .Sort(sort)// optionally
                            .Skip(skip) // optionally
                            .Limit(limit) // optionally
                            .ToList();
```

It will give you a list of BsonDocument with the given parameters. After that, you have to map with your own detail class.

```
var resultList = new List<OrderDetails>();
foreach (var master in list)
            {
                var masterObj = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(master);
                foreach (var item in masterObj)
                {
                    if (item.Key == "orderDetails")
                    {
                        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { }).CreateMapper();
                        var retItem = mapper.Map<OrderDetails>(item.Value);

                        resultList.Add(retItem);
                    }
                }
            }
```